# Find all unambiguous prefixes of a set of strings

Tags: code-golf

For this challenge, you must implement Ruby's [`Abbrev`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/abbrev/rdoc/Abbrev.html) module in as little code as possible.

### Challenge

- The input will be whatever your language has as an array (array, list, sequence, etc.) of strings. You may write a function, or you may accept comma-separated words on STDIN.
- You must then calculate the set of unambiguous prefixes for those strings. This means you must return a hash (or map, object, etc.) of abbreviations to their original strings.

  - A "prefix" is a substring of the original string starting at the beginning of the string. For example, "pref" is an prefix of the word "prefix."
  - An *unambiguous* prefix is one that can only mean one word. For example, if your input is `car,cat`, then `ca` is not an unambiguous prefix because it could mean either "car" or "cat."
  - The exception to this rule is that a word is always a prefix of itself. For example, if you have input such as `car,carpet`, `car:car` must be in your output.
- You can then return the hash/map/object/etc. from your function (or do the equivalent in your language), or print it out to STDOUT in `key:value` pairs in the form of `f:foo,fo:foo,...`. (The key-value pairs may also be separated by whitespace if it makes your code shorter.)

### Test cases

```
Input  code,golf,going
Output c:code,co:code,cod:code,code:code,gol:golf,golf:golf,goi:going,goin:going,going:going

Input  pie
Output p:pie,pi:pie,pie:pie

Input  pie,pier,pierre
Output pie:pie,pier:pier,pierr:pierre,pierre:pierre

Input  a,dog
Output a:a,d:dog,do:dog,dog:dog
```

### Rules

- The input will not contain duplicate elements.
- Your output may be in any order; you don't have to sort it.
- You may not use a built-in `Abbrev` module/function/thing like Ruby's.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes will win!

Comment: Does stdout have to be exactly that format? Or can I do `key:value\nkey:value\nkey:value`... ?

Comment: Rather than redefining the word *abbreviation* you could just use *prefix* with its standard meaning. And I think *unambiguous* conveys the desired property of the keys more effectively than *unique*, for which my first intuition was that you wanted only one prefix per input word.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Good idea; edited.

Comment: May one print the same key multiple times (with the same value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### APL (46)

[(Yes, the APL charset does fit in a byte, with room to spare.)](http://frankenstein.d-n-s.org.uk/~marinus/aplcharset.png)

```
{↑{∆/⍨2=⍴∆←(⊂⍵),∆/⍨⊃¨⍵∘⍷¨∆}¨∪⊃,/{↑∘⍵¨⍳⍴⍵}¨∆←⍵}
```

This is a function that takes a list of strings, and returns a 2-by-N matrix, where each row contains an unambigous prefix and the word it belongs to:

```
{↑{∆/⍨2=⍴∆←(⊂⍵),∆/⍨⊃¨⍵∘⍷¨∆}¨∪⊃,/{↑∘⍵¨⍳⍴⍵}¨∆←⍵}'code' 'golf' 'going'
 c      code  
 co     code  
 cod    code  
 code   code   
 gol    golf  
 golf   golf  
 goi    going 
 goin   going 
 going  going
```

Explanation:

- `∆←⍵`: store the right argument in `∆`.
- `{↑∘⍵¨⍳⍴⍵}¨∆`: for each element of `∆`, get the possible prefixes of that element:

  - `⍳⍴⍵`: get a list from `1` to the length of `⍵`
  - `↑∘⍵¨`: for each of those numbers, get that many elements from `⍵`.
- `∪⊃,/`: concatenate the lists together and take the unique values.
- `{`...`}¨`: for each of the unique prefixes:

  - `∆/⍨⊃¨⍵∘⍷¨∆`: select the words that start with that prefix
  - `(⊂⍵),`: also enclose the prefix, and concatenate
  - `∆/⍨2=⍴∆←`: only return the list if there are two elements (the prefix and one matching word)
- `↑`: turn the list of tuples into a matrix

Comment: The link is broken now...

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.7 - <strike>146</strike> 141 bytes

```python
l=raw_input().split(',')
for w in l:
 for a in range(len(w)):
    e=w[:a+1]
    if e==w or len(filter(lambda b:b.startswith(e),l))==1:print e+':'+w
```

Note that the indentation on lines 4 and 5 is not 4 spaces, that's a side effect of SE's markdown interpreter. That's a literal tab character, so only one byte.

This is not technically up to spec, but I'll change it if Doorknob clarifies. It uses newlines instead of commas to separate the output. For example:

```
$ python2 abbreviations.py <<< code,golf,golfing
c:code
co:code
cod:code
code:code
golf:golf
golfi:golfing
golfin:golfing
golfing:golfing
```

**New:** I was able to get rid of 5 characters by assigning the string that I'm checking to a variable `e`. This means that I only have to type `e` instead of `w[:a]` three times. It also means I save characters by doing `e=w[:a+1]` and changing `...range(1,len(w)+1)` to `range(len(w))`.

---

Explanation:

```python
l=raw_input().split(',') # Gets a line of input from stdin and splits it at every ',' to make a list
for w in l: # For each word in that list...

 for a in range(1,len(w)+1): # For each number a from 1 to the length of that word...

    if (w[:a]==w # w[:a] gets the string w up to the ath index. For example, 'aeiou'[:3] == 'aei'.
                 # We're testing every possible w[:a] to see if it's a unique abbreviation.
                 # However, a word is always its own abbreviation, so we hardcode that in by testing
                 # if w[:a] is the same as w.

or len(filter( # filter takes a function and an iterable as an argument, and returns a list of every
               # element of that iterable where that_function(that_element) returns a True-y value

lambda b:b.startswith(w[:a]),l) # We define an anonymous function that returns True for any string
                                # that begins with our current w[:a]. We filter for words that return
                                # True.

)==1): # If exactly one word returns True for this, it's a unique abbreviation!

     print w[:a]+':'+w # Print the abbreviation, a colon, and the full word.
```

Comment: You could use `sum(b.startswith(e) for b in l)` instead of `len(filter(lambda b:b.startswith(e),l))`

Comment: You can also shorten `b.startswith(e)` to `b.find(e)==0` or `b[:a+1]==e`, and check `<2` on the count instead of `==1`.

Comment: Also do `e=""\n for a in w:\n\te+=a` instead of `for a in range(len(w)):\n\te=w[:a+1]` as it saves 10 chars

Comment: I've made an ungolphed version here for anyone that needs it  https://gist.github.com/stuaxo/c371b2d410191a575b763b74719856c8

Answer (score 3):

## J - 47 char

```
(,.~~.@,~[:(#~1-1({.\e."_1]\.){."1)@;(<\,.<)&.>)
```

J sees strings as just vectors of characters, which means that when it tries to make a list of strings it actually ends up making a table of characters, so the ends get padded with spaces. J's solution to this is called the *box*, so this function takes as argument a boxed list of strings, so as to preserve length.

```
   'code';'golf';'going'
+----+----+-----+
|code|golf|going|
+----+----+-----+
```

Also, J lacks a hash type, so the closest it has to that is a two-column table of items, say boxed strings, for instance. If that is unacceptable and I have to default to the key-value form, I can reformat the output to this form in **67 characters** total:

```
;@|.@,@((<&>',:'),."1,.~~.@,[:(#~1-1({.\e."_1]\.){:"1)@;(<,.<\)&.>)
```

Explanation by explosion:

```
(,.~~.@,[:(#~1-1({.\e."_1]\.){."1)@;(<\,.<)&.>) NB. unambiguous prefixes
                                    (     )&.>  NB. for each string:
                                     <\         NB.   take all prefixes
                                       ,.<      NB.   pair each with string
        [:                         ;            NB. gather up "partial" hashes
          (#~1-                  )@             NB. remove those rows where:
               1({.\        ){."1               NB.   each key
                    e."_1                       NB.   is an element of
               1(        ]\.){."1               NB.   the rest of the keys
 ,.~                                            NB. hash each word to itself
       ,                                        NB. add these rows to hash
    ~.@                                         NB. remove duplicate rows
```

Examples:

```
   (,.~~.@,[:(#~1-1({.\e."_1]\.){."1)@;(<\,.<)&.>) 'pie';'pier';'pierre'
+------+------+
|pie   |pie   |
+------+------+
|pier  |pier  |
+------+------+
|pierre|pierre|
+------+------+
|pierr |pierre|
+------+------+
   NB. 1-char words have to be made into lists with ,
   (,.~~.@,[:(#~1-1({.\e."_1]\.){."1)@;(<\,.<)&.>) (,'a');'dog'
+---+---+
|a  |a  |
+---+---+
|dog|dog|
+---+---+
|d  |dog|
+---+---+
|do |dog|
+---+---+
   NB. "key:value," format, reversed order to save chars
   ;@|.@,@((<&>',:'),."1,.~~.@,[:(#~1-1({.\e."_1]\.){:"1)@;(<,.<\)&.>) 'code';'golf';'going'
goin:going,goi:going,gol:golf,cod:code,co:code,c:code,going:going,golf:golf,code:code,
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell <del>96</del> 87

```
import Data.List
i=inits
f a=a>>= \x->[(y,x)|y<-i x,y/="",y`notElem`(a>>=i)\\i x||y==x]
```

Ungolfed version:

```
 import Data.List
 f a = concatMap (\x ->
     [(y, x) |
      y <- inits x,
      y /= "",
      y `notElem` concatMap inits a \\ inits x || y == x]
     ) a
```

Example:

```
> f ["pi","pier","pierre"]
[("pi","pi"),("pier","pier"),("pierr","pierre"),("pierre","pierre")]
```

I used the `inits` function, which finds all prefixes of a list/string. Does it count as cheating?

Comment: You can replace `concatMap` by `(=<<)`, which is in the Prelude. Saves you 10 characters.

Comment: @Rhymoid Thank you. I removed `concatMap` but I can't save more than 9 characters.

Comment: Oh wait, you're right; Haskell considers `>>=\ ` as a single lexeme. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3 (97)

```python
c=','
S=c+input()
for w in S.split(c):
 e=w
 while e:e<w<w*S.count(c+e)or print(e+':'+w);e=e[:-1]
```

We iterate over prefixes of each word in the input, printing the corresponding prefix/word pair if it either appears exactly once or is to whole word. We take advantage of the short-circuiting behavior of `or` (and `print` being a function) to print only if one of these conditions is met.

The `while` loop repeatedly cuts off the last character to create shorter and shorter prefixes, terminating when the empty string remains. This is the only time we index or slice into anything.

We count the occurrences of the prefix `e` in the input by searching the original comma-separated input string `S` for substrings `','+e`. We prepend a comma to the input string beaforehand. This addition causes an extra empty string element when we `split`, but this has no effect because it has no nonempty substrings.

To check for the case when the substring `e` is the whole word `w`, we compare them using the string comparison operator. This compares lexicographically, so shorter prefixes are smaller. The double comparison fails if either `e==w` or `S.count(c+e)<2`.

If printing outputs in the form `e,w` were allowed, I'd save a character by writing `e+c+w` instead.

Credit to [undergroundmonorail](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/14509/undergroundmonorail) from [whose answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/28280/20260)  I based my overall code structure.

Comment: `(e<w)*S.count(c+e)>1` can be golfed to `e<w<w*S.count(c+e)` to save 2 characters.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! I've added your optimization.

Answer (score 1):

### Ruby, 114

```
def f(l);h={};l.each{|w|w.size.times{|i|k=w[0..i];h[k]=h[k]&&0||w}};h.delete_if{|k,v|v==0};l.each{|w|h[w]=w};h end
```

Ungolfed:

```
def f(list)
  hash = {}
  list.each do |word|
    word.size.times do |i|
      key = word[0..i]
      h[key] = (hash[key] && 0) || word
    end
  end
  hash.delete_if{|key, value| v==0}
  list.each{|word| hash[word] = word}
  hash 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

### k4 (70)

not particularly golfed; i'm sure it could be shorter

pretty similar to the J impl. above, i think -- basically just collects all the (proper) prefixes, removes the words from the prefixes again (to handle the `"car"`/`"carpet"` case), groups them into equivalence classes, picks the classes with only one element, reduces them from lists to strings, and adds in the map from strings to themselves.

```
f:{(x!x),*:'{(&1=#:'x)#x}{x@=y@:&~y in x}.,/'+{1_'(c#,x;(!c:#x)#\:x)}'x}
```

some test cases

note that in `k`/`q`, a string is list of characters, so a string containing only a single character needs to be marked as such using the unary `,` function; & m.m. w.r.t a list of strings containing only a single string

these use `q`'s `show` function, which has built-in formatting for some data structures, to make the results more readable:

```
  .q.show f("code";"golf";"going")
"code" | "code"
"golf" | "golf"
"going"| "going"
,"c"   | "code"
"co"   | "code"
"cod"  | "code"
"gol"  | "golf"
"goi"  | "going"
"goin" | "going"
  .q.show f@,"pie"
"pie"| "pie"
,"p" | "pie"
"pi" | "pie"
  .q.show f("pie";"pier";"pierre")
"pie"   | "pie"
"pier"  | "pier"
"pierre"| "pierre"
"pierr" | "pierre"
  .q.show f(,"a";"dog")
,"a" | ,"a"
"dog"| "dog"
,"d" | "dog"
"do" | "dog"
  .q.show f("car";"carpet")
"car"   | "car"
"carpet"| "carpet"
"carp"  | "carpet"
"carpe" | "carpet"
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript - 212

```
w=prompt(o=[]).split(",");w.map(function(k,l){for(i=0;++i<k.length;){p=k.slice(0,i);if(w.filter(function(r,t){return t!=l}).every(function(r){return r.indexOf(p)}))o.push(p+":"+k)}o.push(k+":"+k)});console.log(o)
```

Initial golf.

Input:

`code,golf,going`

Output:

`["c:code", "co:code", "cod:code", "code:code", "gol:golf", "golf:golf", "goi:going", "goin:going", "going:going"]`

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <s>93</s> 77

With newlines and indentation for readability:

```perl
sub f{
    (map{
        $h{$x}=[($x=$`.$&,$_)x!$h{$x}]while/./g;
        $_,$_
    }@_),map@$_,values%h
}
```

A bit too late and too long, but I'm glad it's finally got below 100. Function returns a list which can be assigned to hash variable:

```
%h = f(qw/code golf going pie pier pierre/);
print "$_ $h{$_}\n" for sort keys %h;
```

and

```
perl prefix.pl
c code
co code
cod code
code code
goi going
goin going
going going
gol golf
golf golf
pie pie
pier pier
pierr pierre
pierre pierre
```

Actually, returned list is not filtered yet - hash construction is completed at the moment of its assignment i.e. outside function. **IF** it's not clean/fair enough, add 3 to count and put function contents into curly braces, prepending `+` - then function returns 'true' hash reference.

Answer (score 1):

### Q: 44 Bytes

```
{x!p@'(?0,&:)'p in\:&1=#:'=,/p:`$(-1_)\'$x}
```

**NOTES**

- Q language has an inner core named internally K4 (used in this answer and another previously answer to this question)
- To test code, download interpreter (kx.com, free for non-commertial
  use, support for Windows, Linux, Mac)

Interpreter admits two syntaxes:

- verbose (more readable names, distinct names for moands and diads, more libraries, ...). Load source file with q extension, or interactive interpreter
- compact (functional inner core, one letter operators, same letter for both uses monad/diad, ...). Load source file with k extension, or interactive interpreter **in k mode** (write \ at prompt). Code must be tested in this mode

The code defines a lambda (anonymous function). To give name to the function we need prefix name: (ex f:{..}), so requires 46 Bytes

**TEST**

(assumming named function: otherwise substitute f for the code)

```
f `code`golf`going

`code`golf`going!(`code`cod`co`c;`golf`gol;`going`goin`goi)
```

returns a dictionary (syntax keys!values). Keys are a list of symbols (`symb`symb..), and values a list of list of symbols. If we execute the sentente at the interactive interpreter, we have a more convenient presentation (each key and associate values at a different line)

```
code | `code`cod`co`c
golf | `golf`gol
going| `going`goin`goi
```

**EXPLANATION**

`x` is the implicit argument to the lambda

`$x` convert symbol list to string list

`(-1_)\`   iterates over each elem of the symbol list

(reads as for each string calculates prefixes (at eat iteration drops last char  of the string (-1_), until empty string)

`$`       transforms to a symbol list again (list of all prefixes)

`p:`       and assigns to p

`,/`       raze all (concatenates and creates a one-level structure)

`=`        classify -> for each unique prefix, associates the corresponding words

`#:'`      calculates length (number of words associated to each prefix)

`1=`       true if length=1 (unambiguous), false otherwise

`&`        where -> index of true elements

`p in\:`   determines for all prefix if they are in unambiguous prefix

`(..)'` applies (..) to each value at right (unambiguous prefix)

`?0,&:`  -> distinct 0 concatenated where (to cope words as prefix of itself)

`p@`       transform indexes to symbols

`x!..`     construct a dictionary with x (words) as keys, and .. as values

Read as:

- Construct and returns a dictionary with the words as keys, and values
  ..
- ... values of indexes at distinct positions 0 (all word) and where
  unambiguous prefix
- ... unambiguous calculated as prefixes that appear only at one word
  (wordlist associates to each symbols has length one)
- ... lists resulting of classifying all unique symbols with corresponding
  words
- ... prefixes calculated by repeating drop last char of each word

Answer (score 1):

**PHP 7.0, 67 bytes** (postdates the challenge)

```php
for(;a&$c=$s[++$k]??($s=$argv[++$i])[$k=+$t=!1];)echo$t.=$c,":$s,";
```

takes input from command line arguments; prints a trailing comma; run with `-nr`.

for **newer PHP**, add one byte: Replace `&a` with `""<`.

for older PHP, use these 70 bytes:

## PHP, 70 bytes

```php
for(;a&$s=$argv[++$i];)for($k=+$t="";a&$c=$s[$k++];)echo$t.=$c,":$s,";
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 23 bytes

```
∋Xa₀Y;?↔⟨∋a₀⟩ᶜ1∧Y;X|∋gj
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6OmpodbZzzc1Vn7cOuE/486uiMSHzU1RFoD5aY8mr8CKADiP5q/8uG2OYaPOpZHWkfUAAXTs/7/j1aIVkrOT0lV0lFKz89JA1OZeelKsTrRSgWZqXBaB0QWQakiiHgikJuSD1SrEAsA)

Takes input as a list through the input variable, and [generates](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10753/85334) a list of `[key, value]` pairs through the output variable. Any input string which is not a prefix of another input string will be generated as a prefix of itself twice, although the header on TIO hides this by using `ᵘ` to obtain the full list instead of `ᶠ`.

```
 X                         X
∋                          is an element of
                           the input variable
    Y                      and Y
  a₀                       is a prefix of
 X                         X.
             ᶜ             The number of ways in which
        ⟨∋  ⟩              an element can be selected from
     ;?↔⟨   ⟩              the input variable
    Y; ↔⟨ a₀⟩              such that it has Y as a prefix
              1            is equal to 1.
               ∧Y          Y is not necessarily 1,
                   |       and the output variable
                Y;X        is the list [Y, X].
                   |       If every choice from the first rule has been taken already,
                           the output variable is
                    ∋      an element of
                   |       the input variable
                     gj    paired with itself.
```

Comment: If duplicates in the output are not tolerated, add three bytes to wrap the whole thing in `{}ᵘ`, unless there's some shorter way to either exclude something form being a prefix of itself, or generate every necessary output pair without the extra rule `∋gj`.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 38 bytes

thanks Erik the Outgolfer for reminding me to use a single-byte character encoding

```apl
{⊃,/⍵{b,¨⍨(⊂¨⍵~⊃,/a~⊂⍵)∪b←⊂⊂⍺}¨a←,\¨⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZA9TsNAEIV7n8LdOJIjkOg4C83Gf6ywspbtBlmmCChKghxBwQWorDRUaSh9lLmIebu2yTrNzvvem539EVm6DJ9FqpJlkIqikEHPxy@pePtx21d8ePVvuDlXK79ruWk9Pmy0OL@YRKBsQAvenVbYoUkbv3XXCrD/YJrrPtZhc8Sm7ueOt584osgDrOWjLPoSaYU@3n/nkDEG3HNzoljIlACIcn5/I/VEtUOBCiNyKVFpbIpcJ@SWrkcB0IQLaDWDcE6RhZgzTRsonqH8P2PA9TUnF8PxfDyfMonB5kYZMkOQ0tbRBM4F8rHk0fAcq8uz8wmt/smJLMshAQrV@DkahG4MR1dLZetkgj8)

Comment: Um... I don't see any one of the bad characters that you can't use with Adám's SBCS here... :P

Comment: without noticing, i've picked the wrong interpreter version again... thanks for halving my byte count :)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 76 bytes

```perl
map{say"$, $a"if($,=substr$a,0,$_)eq$a||2>grep/^$,/,@F}1..length($a=$_)for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcqxDoIwEIDhVyHkBkyOUkwYMUxsvoLmTA5sgrRc60DAV/ckDv83/YFlalRfFLZIaw6YAeVuKADb@H7EJEBoEe4nXoD2/XwZhUN1A6yw6z@1MRPPY3oWQO0xDV66XjU4zo7kj/DXh@T8HLW8NsbWVkv6AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## Python (127)

So I couldn't comment @undergroundmonorail, but I thought that taking a dictionary approach would be better? I'm sure with some list/dictionary comprehension it could be cut down tremendously too, but can't get it to work with popping from the dict.

```
i=raw_input().split(",")
d = {}
for x in i:
    for c in range(1,len(x)+1):
        if x[:c] in d:
            del d[x[:c]]
        else:
            d[x[:c]]=x
print d
```

The print will output the dictionary, unordered.

EDIT: Ahh I missed the car:car / car:carpet criteria. Maybe a length check?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems to alternately add and delete the prefix entry each time it is encountered, so wouldn't an ambiguous prefix appear if it occurs in 3 words?

Answer (score 0):

### Groovy - 212 chars

Golfed:

```
c="collectEntries";f="findAll";def g={def h=[:].withDefault{[]};it.each{def w->w.size().times{ h[w[0..it]] << w}};(h."$f"{k,v->v.size()==1}."$c"{k,v->[k,v[0]]}).plus(h."$f"{k,v->v.contains(k)}."$c"{k,v->[k,k]})}
```

example output:

```
println g(["code","golf","going"])

[c:code, co:code, cod:code, code:code, gol:golf, golf:golf, goi:going, goin:going, going:going]
```

Ungolfed:

```
def g = { def list ->
    def hash = [:].withDefault{[]}
    list.each {
        def word -> word.size().times{ hash[word[0..it]] << word }
    }

    def map = hash.findAll{ k,v -> v.size() == 1 }.collectEntries{ k,v -> [k,v[0]] }
    map.plus(hash.findAll{ k,v -> v.contains(k) }.collectEntries{ k,v -> [k,k] }
    map
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 88 bytes

```javascript
L=>L.map(s=>[...s].map(c=>L.filter(t=>t>S&t<S+'~',S+=c)[1]&&s>S||(R[S]=s),S=''),R={})&&R
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY2xDsIgFAD/hgcpkjjXxxd0gpEwNFiaGoSmj3Sx@uuonS53yz3GfaSwLWu95HKfWsQ2oB7Uc1w5oXZKKfKnhX@OS6rTxivqqi2rN9vBB6TtMAh39YyRtsfBjbMeSUiLAEIafL0FY6b1oWQqaVKpzDxyB@F3BAlzSfHEkmfwQvStfQE)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 95 bytes

```sh
local -A m
for w;{m[$w]=$w;x=
for c (${(s::)w})x+=$c&&[ ${(M)@:#$x*} = $w ]&&m[$x]=$w
}
local m
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCsMgFAX3nuJDP6ItuYBBaA/QE4Qsgok2oLWYhdLg2Y0mizeLgXn/7VM046xYryYL3Qsc0T5A7Hc3YBwlxj7JUylguLNNCB4zTw@JitIBqnrzp7hhumeQgBFGSmuaWkoyuX5d4YRoUH5ewHirK9avqea3LhfbwonQzASzN@UA)

The only way to "return" an associative array in Bash/Zsh is by declaring it without the `local` keyword and then accessing it in the parent scope. [This would save one byte.](https://tio.run/##qyrO@J@moVn9v6SyILU4tURBN91RIddWQ5MrLb9Iody6OjdapTzWVqXcusIWLJSsoKFSrVFsZaVZXqtZoW2rkqympgEUUgaK@mo6WCmrVGjV1uoaamrW1AD1VoD0ctX@r@XiSlNIzk9JVUjPz0kDEpl56VwwO3OBcgWZqeh8EC4CE0WocokKKflIuv8DAA) However, I/O via variables is generally frowned upon, so we print the array definition instead.

```sh
local -A m                          # declare m as associative
                                    # "local" is shorter than "typeset"/"declare"
for w;{                             # for each word
    m[$w]=$w                        # the word is a prefix of itself
    x=                              # ensure x is empty
    for c (${(s::)w})               # for each character in the word
        x+=$c &&                    # append to x (building a prefix
          [ ${(M)@:#$x*} = $w ] &&  # if the only match is the word itself:
          m[$x]=$w                  # ... then x is a prefix of w
}
local m                             # print m
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 84 bytes

Just noticed there's already an existing Ruby solution, oh well. This basically improves on the old solution by picking prefixes in a smarter way (eliminating the need to add each word as a "prefix" at the end) and counting prefixes to check uniqueness before adding them to the hash, instead of overwriting the value with a dummy if there is a duplicate and then erasing the entry.

```ruby
->w{h={};w.map{|e|(1..e.size).map{|i|w.count{|d|d[0,i]==e[0,i]}<2?h[e[0,i]]=e:0}};h}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYlBDsIgFET3nIKFC02UVJdW6kEaYrB8y08qkNKGKHB2rO3ivZnMjPPzUyQvpyZEzWOuA3tLFxOk/ZkxYB6/cNgmTIF1djZTTCqptjqi4BzWzLfLXbdbFxyuVc61ziVoHID2MHlCqaOy3T2YdwNOgoBRpbNqee3wWoSmJw7hD10YV41AJFW2/wE)